# Python flask send_from_directory()

Tags: python, файлы, flask

мне нужно написать функцию, которая будет скачивать файлы с сервера
и вот все работало отлично когда надо было скачивать по одному файлу я тогда использовал

```
@app.route('return_files/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def return_files(file)
    return send_from_directory(directory="pdf", filename=file, as_attachment=True)
```

теперь мне нужно чтобы эта функция возвращала несколько файлов то-есть как-то так:

```
 @app.route('return_files/', methods=['GET','POST'])
    def return_files(files)
        for file in files:
        return send_from_directory(directory="pdf", filename=file, as_attachment=True)
```

этот app.route и вся функция выглядит очень абстрактно, суть в том что раньше когда я нажимал на кнопку 'скачать файл' он скачивался, теперь с большим количеством файлов это не проходит, как это можно решить?

Comment: Протокол HTTP в принципе не позволяет отправлять в ответе больше одного файла одновременно, так что и фласк вам тут никак не поможет. Запакуйте файлы в zip-архив, например

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге я решил просто соединить файлы в один и вернуть его.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger


@app.route('return_files/', methods=['GET','POST'])
    def return_files(files)
        merger = PdfFileMerger()
        for file in files:
            merger.append(file)
        merger.write("result.pdf")
        merger.close()
        return send_from_directory(directory="pdf", filename='result.pdf', as_attachment=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` прерывает выполнение функции с сразу возвращает результат. В вашем случае могу посоветовать два варианта:

- Завести список и `append` туда каждый файл.

  ```
   @app.route('return_files/', methods=['GET','POST'])
   def return_files(files)
      file_list = []
      for file in files:
          file_list.append(send_from_directory(directory="pdf", 
                           filename=file, 
                           as_attachment=True))
      return file_list
  ```
- Написать генератор для получения всех возможных файлов. Читайте про `yeld`
  Ну и советую немножко зарефакторить, потому что логика получения файлов, это не логика rout`ов

---

И да, обратите внимание на комментарий [andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal)

Comment: Этот способ со списком уже пробовался, не работает )